# How to Track Two Screens(Activities) Using Google Analytics in Android

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

This is Actual code.

Comment: There's is nothing constructive about your question. This is not how SO works. We don't just hand over code. The code you have posted is auto generated by an IDE and has nothing to do with your question. The idea behind this website is to get help on something you have already tried working on. I have worked to Google Analytics, and the tutorials are sufficient to achieve what you are asking. Attempt it first, then come back if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

Define a Tracker like described in the [google analytics developer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#tracking-methods) guide and set different screen names for the activities.

1. Setup your Project in the Google Analytics console
2. Update Manifest
3. Update your Activity or Fragment classes

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Get tracker.
    Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
        TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

    // Set screen name.
    t.setScreenName("YourActivityName");

    // Send a screen view.
    t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
   }
   ```

For beginning with Google Analytics use the App tracker. For this you don't have to define any xml like in the beginners guide

4. Send Events

   ```
   Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
       TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

   // Build and send an Event.
   t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
       .setCategory(getString(categoryId))
       .setAction(getString(actionId))
       .setLabel(getString(labelId))
       .build());
   ```

Comment: I need xml files also pls post here